# How do you batch add column headers to all CSV files in a directory and reserve those files out?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have hundreds of CSV files without headers that get exported from some software I use. The number of columns and the exact column headers may vary between batches, but never varies within batches.

I am learning Pandas and I need some help to put together a very simple notebook that loads all the CSV files in a directory, and adds the column headers I choose to all the files in that directory and saves them as the same CSV files (same names) but now with headers included in the file.

As I said, certain batches will vary in the number of columns that need headers and what the headers will be so it would be nice to preserve the ability to change the headers at will.

I have the following code and it works great with one file. How do I loop over all files in the directory, add the same headers, and save the files.

```
import pandas as pd
df_csv = pd.read_csv('/Users/F/Desktop/FPython/File1.csv', names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df_csv.to_csv('/Users/F/Desktop/FPython/File1.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pandas` module, specifically [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) methods. This way you can modify the imported dataframe with needed headers as column names and then save the modified dataframe back to csv.

You can use `glob` module to iterate over all the `.csv` files in your folder:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('./*.csv')

def manipulate_headers(df):
    df.set_axis(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

for file_name in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    df = manipulate_headers(df)
    df.to_csv(file_name)
```

Where `manipulate_headers()` is your method on handling the headers data and changing the columns names, I just provide one possible manipulation of setting new index names.

**Note**:
I do recommend you to save the modified files in a new folder under new file names, so you always have a backup with the original files, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I am using the code snippet I added to the original question - I'm confused on how to loop over every file in the directory and save with the file's original name.

Comment: @Lgeo, you are on a right path, see my edited answer :)

Comment: thanks for pointing me to glob, looks interesting. Three issues
1. I loaded your code snippet and I'm getting an error saying that read_csv is not defined. 
2. In looking for info on glob I cannot find how to edit the manipulate_headers to add headers
3. do I need to mix your code snipped with what I had in pandas as well.
sorry but I'm totally lost on this one.

Comment: @Lgeo, You are right, I've forgotten to use the `read_csv` method from `pandas`. 
`manipulate_headers()` would be your own method (function) where you modify the headers according to your requirements. I've updated the asnwer with more elaborate code.

Comment: thanks for this - it's exactly what I needed. Only thing I added was setting the index=False and its excellent. Thanks!